# Task скачивания файла

Tags: c#, winforms, task

Запутался в одном вопросе, просьба знающих помочь.
При открытии формы проверяю, существует ли на жёстком диске файл. Если нет - качаем его из интернета. При этом на форме показывается прогресс скачивания. Тут всё нормально. Но, если закрыть форму во время скачивания файла и открыть снова, скачивание файла не начинается заново. Код такой

```
  private async void fPreTrain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {             
            string path = Application.StartupPath + @"\vids\warmup.mp4";
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = path;
            if (!Classes.Options.WarmupFileLoaded)
            {// Файла нет, качаем
                layoutControlItem2.Visibility = DevExpress.XtraLayout.Utils.LayoutVisibility.Always;
                string clean_path = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
                if (!Directory.Exists(clean_path))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(clean_path);

                try
                {
                    await Task.Run(() => Classes.HttpManager.DownloadFile(
                       "https://hardworkandsweat.com//content/videos/warmup.mp4", path, progressDownload));                  
                }
                catch
                {
                    Classes.Options.WarmupFileLoaded = false; 
                    layoutControlItem2.Visibility = DevExpress.XtraLayout.Utils.LayoutVisibility.Never;
                    if (Classes.MyForm.Show("Ошибка","Не получилось скачать файл разминки. Открыть видео в браузере?", Classes.MyForm.ftypes.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://hardworkandsweat.com//content/videos/warmup.mp4");
                    return;
                }

                layoutControlItem2.Visibility = DevExpress.XtraLayout.Utils.LayoutVisibility.Never;
                Classes.Options.WarmupFileLoaded = true;
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
            }   
            else       
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
        }
```

**update:**
Подебажил. Обнаружил следующее: при первом открытии формы файл качается корректно. Закрыл форму во время скачивания и открыл заново. Когда запускается метод DownloadFile, почему-то уже не получается подключиться к серверу. При этом, если прогу закрыть совсем, и открыть заново. Всё качает

```
public static void DownloadFile(string url,string save_to,DevExpress.XtraEditors.ProgressBarControl progress)
        {
            try
            {
                WebRequest sizeRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                sizeRequest.Method = "HEAD";

                int size = (int)sizeRequest.GetResponse().ContentLength;

                progress.Invoke(
                    (MethodInvoker)(() => progress.Properties.Maximum = size));             

                // Download the file
                HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)
WebRequest.Create(url);
                httpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
                Stream ftpStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();

                // create and open a FileStream, using calls dispose when done
                using (var fs = File.Create(save_to))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
                    int read;
                    while ((read = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        fs.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                        int position = (int)fs.Position;
                        progress.Invoke(
                            (MethodInvoker)(() => progress.Position = position));
                        // progress.Position = position;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(e.Message);
            }          
        }
```

понял в чём был косяк. поправил таким образом:

```
 public static class HttpManager
    {
        static WebRequest sizeRequest;
        static HttpWebRequest httpRequest;
        public static void StopDownload()
        {
            sizeRequest.Abort();
            sizeRequest = null;
            httpRequest.Abort();
            httpRequest = null;
        }              
        public static void DownloadFile(string url,string save_to,DevExpress.XtraEditors.ProgressBarControl progress)
        {
            try
            {
                sizeRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                int size = (int)sizeRequest.GetResponse().ContentLength;

                progress.Invoke(
                    (MethodInvoker)(() => progress.Properties.Maximum = size));             

                // Download the file
              httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)
WebRequest.Create(url);
                httpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
                Stream ftpStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();

                // create and open a FileStream, using calls dispose when done
                using (var fs = File.Create(save_to))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
                    int read;
                    while ((read = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        if (progress != null)
                        {
                            fs.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                            int position = (int)fs.Position;
                            progress.Invoke(
                                (MethodInvoker)(() => progress.Position = position));
                            // progress.Position = position;
                        }
                        else
                            return;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(e.Message);
            }          
        }
```

Теперь ругается на стрим когда код доходит до записи в файл, говорит что файл уже занят другим процессом. Как мне прекратить использование файла при закрытии формы?

Comment: Task тут ни при чем, проблема у вас со стандартным http-клиентом

Comment: Кратко: надо отменять запрос при закрытии формы.

Comment: нельзя ли немного подробнее?

Comment: Скорее всего когда Вы закрыли окно, то при очередной попутке обновить уже не существующий `progressDownload` (если это поле или прогрессбар)... Смотрите как у Вас работает `Classes.HttpManager.DownloadFile`

Comment: При втором вызове метода Classes.HttpManager.DownloadFile  int size = (int)sizeRequest.GetResponse().ContentLength; отваливается по таймауту. не могу понять почему

Comment: @Antykus, вы открыли сокет/соединение, поработали с ним, и не высвободили ресурс, а закрыли форму. Перед закрытием, надо убедиться в том что ресурс освобождён, если протокол подрузомевал сигнал отмены - послать отмену, и только потом давать форме закрыться.

Comment: я понимаю суть, но не знаю как это выразить в коде. Подскажите пожалуйста приблизительно как это осуществить. Метод загрузки файла вызывается из метода загрузки формы таском @test123

Comment: Без кода Classes.HttpManager ничего не могу подсказать.

Comment: @test123 добавил в текст вопроса код метода

Comment: Вот, теперь видно что есть Stream ftpStream, который попросту не закрывается. Нужно следить за ним, и в случае закрытия формы, делать ftpStream.close(); внутри метода.

Comment: @test123 выполнение кода после закрытия формы и открытия заново стопорится на строке "int size = ...", до стрима то есть не доходит

Comment: Если проект не большой, не могли бы вы его прикрепить?

Comment: @test123 проект здоровенный, и к сожалению, не хотелось бы делиться со всем миром этим, пускай и туповатым, кодом

Comment: @test123 если вас не затруднит, гляньте пожалуйста мою последнюю правку

Answer (score 0):

Костыльно, но решил. Вот так:

```
 public static class HttpManager
    {
        static WebRequest sizeRequest;
        static HttpWebRequest httpRequest;
        static Stream ftpStream;
        static FileStream fs;
        public static void StopDownload()
        {
            sizeRequest.Abort();
            sizeRequest = null;
            httpRequest.Abort();
            httpRequest = null;
            if (ftpStream!=null)
            {
                ftpStream.Close();
                ftpStream = null;
            }                  

            if (fs!=null)
            {
                fs.Close();
                fs = null;
            }   
        }      

        public static void DownloadFile(string url,string save_to,DevExpress.XtraEditors.ProgressBarControl progress)
        {
            try
            {
                sizeRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                int size = (int)sizeRequest.GetResponse().ContentLength;

                progress.Invoke(
                    (MethodInvoker)(() => progress.Properties.Maximum = size));             

              httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)
WebRequest.Create(url);
                httpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();

                ftpStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
                fs = File.Create(save_to);               
                byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
                int read;
                while (fs!=null && (read = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {                       
                        fs.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                        int position = (int)fs.Position;
                        progress.Invoke(
                            (MethodInvoker)(() => progress.Position = position));  
                }                
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (e.Message.Contains("Запрос отменен"))
                    return;

                throw new Exception(e.Message);
            }
            StopDownload();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Если вы уберёте все слова static и при использовании HttpManager будете создавать на одно соединение один экземпляр - это перестанет быть костылём.